# Generate a alphanumeric random and unique string with size of 8 in java(uppercase letter required)

Tags: java

I am trying to generate random and unique string of size 8 which must contains digit and uppercase letter.
Please help me.
for example  **AB2CDE11**

Comment: How exactly does *8 bit* **string** look like? AFAIK each character is 8 bits, therefore it would be a char, not a string.

Comment: 8 Bit? Byte? Characters?

Comment: @Ace, you are much more likely to get help if you show some attempt you have tried already and explain exactly where you are seeing an issue.

Comment: I tried RandomStringUtils.random(8, true, true).toUpperCase(); but it sometimes give only characters

Comment: I want somewhat like AB2CDE11

Comment: Random Strings may or may not contain numbers - obviously you are not guaranteed it. RandomStringUtils is your best option.

Comment: @Josh .please give solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out: [RandomStringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/RandomStringUtils.html) and pick the most appropriate method! I would suggest:

```
RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(8)
```

Comment: I used it ,but it only give String like **aYDNDBpd** .there is no digit in string

Comment: @Ace You can generate with digit as well by using different method:
`RandomStringUtils.random(final int count, final boolean letters, final boolean numbers)` 
By using that you can specify length, if letters or digits should be included as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
    /**
     * This method produces a random password with combination of alphabets in lower and Upper case along with numbers
     */

        char[] characterSet={'a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
                'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q',
                'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
        char[] charSetUpper={'A', 'B', 'C', 'D',
                'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q',
                'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };
        char[] numbers={'0', '1', '2', '3', '4',
                '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};

        List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<Character>();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        int alphaRand=new Random().nextInt(4);

        alphaRand=alphaRand>0?alphaRand:alphaRand+1;

        for (int loop = 0; loop<alphaRand; loop++) {
            int index = new Random().nextInt(characterSet.length);
            characters.add(characterSet[index]);
        }
        for (int loop = 0; loop<4-alphaRand; loop++) {
            int index = new Random().nextInt(charSetUpper.length);
            characters.add(charSetUpper[index]);
        }
        for (int loop = 0; loop<4; loop++) {
            int index = new Random().nextInt(numbers.length);
            characters.add(numbers[index]);
        }

        while(characters.size()!=0){
            int randPicker = (int)(Math.random()*characters.size());
            sb.append(characters.remove(randPicker));
        }

        String nonce = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(nonce);
```